# Spacing between paragraph and list when using usepackage{parskip} and usepackage{enumitem}

Tags: enumitem, parskip

I have an item list that I would like to start on a new line, but without a full paragraph space before the first item. I try the different options in enumitem to control this and they work they way I expect. However, when I use the parskip package, the behaviour changes dramatically.

For example, the following has the desired spacing:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, pdftext, draft]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
%
\begin{document}
Bunch of text here.

New paragraph here\newline
New line here.
\begin{itemize}[partopsep=0pt, topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=*]
\item First item
\item second one
\item etc.
\end{itemize}
More here.
\end{document}
```

But when I introduce the parskip, it adds a bunch of extra space before the list:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, pdftext, draft]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
%
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\parfillskip = 2em plus 1fil %Override parfill default (\parfillskip = 30pt plus 1fil)
%
\usepackage{enumitem}

%
\begin{document}
Bunch of text here.

New paragraph here\newline
New line here.
\begin{itemize}[partopsep=0pt, topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=*]
\item First item
\item second one
\item etc.
\end{itemize}
More here.
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to have the list spacing I want AND the paragraph formatting I get from parskip?

Answer (score 5):

If you want bad typography, just set `topsep=-\parskip`; if you want less bad typography, don't use `parskip`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Bunch of text here.

New paragraph here\newline
New line here.
\begin{itemize}[partopsep=0pt, topsep=-\parskip, parsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=*]
\item First item
\item second one
\item etc.
\end{itemize}
More here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, I replace `\usepackage{parskip}` with `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`, manually end paragraphs ('\\') and live without the parfill behaviour.

Comment: Do you mind to explain?

Comment: Ah, I see, seems I can't have it both ways then. If I leave out parskip the subsequent paragraphs get squeezed together. So, it looks like I will have to live with `topsep=-\parskip`

Comment: note that the package description of `parskip` does say that it is not really in the same league as a “proper class”; for a reference to one such, see my [faq answer on ‘zero paragraph skip’](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=parskip)

Comment: in my previous characteristically hamfisted comment, please read "indent" for "skip" as the last word of the link.  (i almost never move fast enough to use the "re-edit" facility: sorry.)